# How to let the webBrowser_Documentcompleted fire multiple times

Tags: c#

I made a simple webbrowser in c#, which keeps reloading a page and then does something when the page is loaded.

However, after the first time, the following function doesn't fire anymore:

```
public void gotourl()
{
   webBrowser.Navigate("Stackoverflow.com");
}

 public void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Page loaded succesfully."); // only fires once
   // waiting for a few seconds by using a timer
   gotourl();
}
```

However, I did reload the page. The documentcompleted state simply doesn't fire again.

Is there a way to let the function fire every time I navigate to an url?

( I also tried webBrowser.Refresh() )

EDIT: I added the unbelievable solution..

Comment: Someone posted the WebBrowser.Navigated, but that also only fires once. It should be possible to let it fire multiple times?!

Comment: In an other stackoverflow answer, it is suggested to use webBrowser1.Refresh(); , but even after that the DocumentCompleted or Navigated doesn't fire a second time.

Comment: I tried navigating to another url, then navigating back to the same url. Yet the webbrowser doesn't call DocumentCompleted other than the first time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is unbelievable. After hours of searching and trying things, I found the answer.

In the properties of webBrowser1, I set the property "AllowNavigation" to false.

If set to false, it only registers the webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted() function only ONCE, but when the AllowNavigation property is set to true(which it is by default), the DocumentCompleted() function repeats.

I have no clue why it works this way and I hope people with the same problem find this answer, as it is the only answer on the net..

Comment: Interestingly, I found out, that after the `DocumentCompleted` event fired, the webbrowser interprets JavaScript if contained and is not ready in all cases.
I found also, that the `ProgressChanged` event finally fires once more after the `DocumentCompleted` event with the event arguments `CurrentProcess = 0` and `MaximumProcess=0`. I reloaded the next page after that occurrence, and that worked.